# Error upgrading to Azure DevOPS 2019 from TFS 2013 Update 5

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are trying to upgrade our TFS 2013 Update 5 to Azure DevOPS 2019 but I am getting an error that "Direct upgrade from TFS 2013 is not supported. You must uninstall TFS2013 before you can install this version of Azure DevOps Server".

So is there any way to upgrade to Azure DevOPS 2019 without uninstalling  TFS 2013 Update 5.

Comment: Upgrading from TFS 2013.5 to Azure DevOps 2019 is supported. Could you share your detailed steps of upgrading TFS? Please review the following link and follow the instructions to upgrade your server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops.

Comment: The error message is telling you what to do. Did you do what it said?

Comment: Also, be aware that the minimum required versions of Windows and SQL Server have changed between 2013 and 2019. Refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops#operating-systems. You probably aren't going to be able to do an in-place upgrade, as you are going to need, at a minimum, to update your SQL server version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If installer says you need to uninstall tfs first, just do it. There is no command line parameters or something else to get around that. Uninstall is just an additional step in normal upgrade process. Do not forget to create backups before upgrade. [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Before anything gets uninstalled, check the system requirements. There's OS compatibility overlap, but not SQL Server overlap, between 2013 and 2019. This upgrade would be better as a migration to new hardware instead of trying to do it in-place.